# How to specify ExcludeFromCodeCoverage at assembly level for dot net framework class library?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, csproj

I want to exclude a test project from code coverage, I do see equivalent of same in .Net core 3.1 is adding below line of code in csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage" />
</ItemGroup>
```

How to specify same thing in dot net framework 4.8 csproj class library file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<AssemblyAttribute>` item only works in SDK-based projects. So if you create an SDK-based .NET Framework csproj, it will work (do note this might clash with any existing `AssemlyInfo.cs` if one exists). e.g.:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Otherwise, I worked on a similar situation a while back and created a drop-in replacement for the assembly info generation logic for non-SDK csproj, see https://github.com/dasMulli/AssemblyInfoGenerationSdk for that (do log issues if it doesn't work). Do note that you may need to disable some generation of e.g. Version attributes similar to SDK-style projects so it doesn't clas with existing `AssemblyInfo.cs` files.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative for this (I've only tested it in .NET 6) is to include an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in your project that includes the following:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
```

### UPDATE:

This works in at least .NET 6 and .NET Standard 2.1. It definitely doesn't work in .NET Standard 2.0 as the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute cannot be used with the `assembly:` declaration in that version. **I haven't tried it in any other versions.**

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work on .NET Standard projects...

Comment: @derekbaker783 I just tried it in a new .NET Standard 2.1 project and it works absolutely fine

Comment: Right, I meant to say Standard2.0.

Comment: Seems you are correct, if vague. `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` is not valid with an assembly declaration in .NET Standard 2.0